# Are the planets of our solar system ( like Brihaspati, Shukra, Chandra etc) Devas or the abodes of the respective Devas?

Tags: scripture, vedas, gods, astrology, navagraha

We all know that Brihaspati is Teacher of Devas. Shukracharya is also teacher of Daityas. Mangal Deva etc. Are also Deva. So are the planets and sun moon just their abodes or is Surya Deva really a sphere of Hydrogen changing to Helium etc. ? If these planets and sun, moon are the very Deva, then does man landing on moon lands on Chandra Deva's body? Did the satellite of India 'MangalaYaana' land on Mangal's body.? Then why did not these Devatas talked to Human beings.?

And if this is their Abode, then where is the well expounded aishwarya of their respective Lokas- the throne of these Deva, their servants, palace etc.?

We cannot deny that the planet our sages pointed in sky and calling them Devatas, are not the same planets and celestial bodies that have been reached by humans now.

And if human being is this able to reach their Abode, where has gone the power of these Devatas? Why did not the gatekeepers of their Loka obstruct satellites and human beings reaching Saturn, Mangal, Moon etc.

The celestial objects that we see now are the very ones who were pointed by the Shastras and Purans. So these celestial objects have to be- either the Devatas, or their Loka. And in both case, if human being is this able that to even reach them, where has gone their power? This all leads to us thinking that all things written in our Shastras are just some very very intelligent imagination by some very very wise and intellectual persons. And the GOD is also one of this Imagination. And if it be so, then does God exist. And if the things written them are true, then where is the validity of the fact that has been questioned?

Please note, then I am not a science based atheist hypocrite. I am very devoted to Mother Lalita. But doubts of this kind, as I mentioned in my question, make me feel if God even exists or not. Moreover, if God exists and the composers of Veda Purans were blessed by this Same God, then how could they be so wrong in writing these facts about the celestial bodies?

Comment: There are planets which are physical entities. These physical entities have governing deities or adhi devatas. These adhi devatas are Brihaspati, Angaraka etc. These governing deities in turn have authorities they answer to ( pratyadhidevata. For e.g., Angaraka is answerable to Subrahmanya).

Comment: They are the physical entities. They are literally not the Mangal, shani etc., Also a note to point. There is no word like Shani deva. The word deva is only added to Sun,moon among the planets because they are vedic gods. The space bodies we see are not the bodies of Brihaspati etc., Deva should not be added to shani, mangal, kuja etc., The word is **Shanaishchara Not  "Shanishwara**

Comment: Chandra is a Deva. Chandra Loka is his abode. Now ur question is "Is the Moon we see on the night sky the Devata or his  Loka ?... It is the Deva..I think. .. we can't see his abode i guess just like we can't see his chariot etc.

Comment: तुष्टो ददासि वै राज्यं रुष्टो हरसि तत्क्षणात् ।।८।।
देवासुरमनुष्याश्च  सिद्घविद्याधरोरगा: ।
त्वया विलोकिता: सर्वे नाशंयान्ति समूलत:।।९।।
    प्रसाद कुरु  मे  देव  वाराहोऽहमुपागत ।
       एवं स्तुतस्तद  सौरिग्र्रहराजो महाबल

Comment: Dasharath krita shani stotram. Calls him Deva. Is dasharath wrong. Or had Dasharath not created  this stotram.? And if dasharath has not created and it is Imagination, then what is validity of our Shastras

Comment: Sanskrit Dhatu "**Grah**" means "put on"or "grasp" or one that moves. But as per science definition is, something which revolves around a nearby star. So, Surya is also "Graha" but not planet. Even lunar nodes, "Rahu" and "Ketu" are Shadow Grahas. (Chaya Grahas).

Comment: I know this well. But since there is no word in English for Graham, so I used planet only to describe all . Please someone answer my question .

Comment: It is talking to yourself if you do not write @username whom you are replying. It is only a respect. Which scripture has this stotram? What is the story of Dasharatha worshipping Shani? Why is this only popular in north India? Shani is not a deva. In many places there is only shanaishchara. Shanishwara is not used. These planets are not literally those devatas and it is not their abode. They are the adhidevatas of the planet. There are other lokas which we can't reach through spaceships.

Comment: Scriptures personify many inanimate things like mountains, rivers etc.. Ganga , Saraswati are for example living Deities in the Scriptures but they are also rivers. Similarly for the Grahas.

Comment: @Rickross if they just pe4sonify inanimate lifeless unconscious objects, then why would Shankaracharya eulogise Maa Gangaa saying that you are great mother etc. Was He a fool?

Comment: That is what i am saying too. they are not inanimate for we Hindus. And the Scriptures mention them as persons or living deities.

Comment: @Rickross and other you all may be thinking that I am offending our Dharma Scriptures etc. But it is not so  actually I just want to know it whether God is real or not . I do not want to do stupidity by devoting myself to unrealistic God, if God is not true. And if God is true, info not want to do even more stupid thing of not devoting myself to God. So this only I want to know.

Comment: Man going to the moon is one big lie. Problem solved. Look for youtube videos debunking the supposed Moon landings.
Hare Krishna!!!

Comment: @CarloJael even if man has not gone to moon, but satellites do have reached moon, mars, and even Saturn. What is then going to happen?